# Is it possible to deploy only Application Parameters (cloud.xml) in Service Fabric without having to change the Application version?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

Is there a possibility to deploy only Application Parameters (cloud.xml) somehow without having to redeploy the code or upgrade the application version? For example after deploying the Application on Service fabric cluster, there could be a minor thing I might need to change in one of the parameters in cloud.xml. And it won't make sense to upgrade the version of the Application for this minor change.
I have combed through various sites but did not find anything suitable.

Comment: No, when you do a config only upgrade, then (as far as I'm aware) the config and application versions have to be incremented. Application versions are just strings, so as long as they are unique, you can call them anything. They don't (again, as far as I'm aware) have to be semver for example. They just have to be unique. Not even sequential I don't think?

Comment: Could you update it through [Service Fabric REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/)?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that using APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say - no, you can't do this. Here is what [Service Fabric application upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade) says on this -

> During an upgrade, Service Fabric compares the new application manifest with the previous version and determines which services in the application require updates. Service Fabric compares the version numbers in the service manifests with the version numbers in the previous version. If a service has not changed, that service is not upgraded.